# Resumen diario de ventas o formulario con las ventas del dia Tkinter , python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

que tal soy nuevo estoy aprendiendo programación , tengo un proyecto de la facu y estoy haciendo un sistema de ventas con tkinter y python, junto con sqlite

ya tengo casi todo listo, puedo largar la factura de la venta pero me gustaría que me muestre el resumen de todas las ventas del día alguien me podría orientar a como poder hacer eso ? no creo que sea difícil pero no se los comando o los llamados a la base de datos que hay que hacer!! muchas gracias desde ya !

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones, considera que para que se te pueda apoyar debes proveer un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable

Comment: hola que tal, estoy aprendiendo a usar stack over flow disculpa , que consejo me podes dar al respecto de como publicar

Comment: Lee por favor el enlace que te deje en el otro comentario